# Automatlcally distinguish the caller in MEF

Tags: c#, metadata, mef

Using MEF, from inside the exporter, is it possible to find out who is importer using metadata ?

for example is this possible:

```
[Export("Config")]
String Config()
{
   if (importer.metedata["name"] == "Circle")
   return "R=10";
}
```

This way importer doesn't need to pass something (his name, here) to tell the exporter who is he.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. It makes more sense to do this:

```
[Export("Config")]
string GetConfigurationValue(string name)
{
   if (name == "Circle")
   {
       return "R=10";
   }
   throw new ArgumentException(
       string.Format("Unknown configuration value '{0}'", name));
}
```

And the class which imports this method could look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IDrawer))]
public class CircleDrawer : IDrawer
{
    [Import("Config")]
    public Func<string,string> ConfigGetter { get; set; }

    public void Draw()
    {
        string configuration = this.ConfigGetter("Circle");
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that directly importing and exporting methods (as `System.Action` or `System.Func`) is the quick and dirty way.

It is better to declare a `IConfigurationProvider` interface instead and export that at the class level. This has two advantages:

- the interface documentation is where you can document the contract that the importer and exporter have to agree on.
- it eliminates the needs for those pesky strings in the import/export attributes by replacing them by `typeof(IConfigurationProvider)`.

Comment: This should work, but wouldn't you need a corresponding `Import` attribute on the `name` parameter?  Otherwise, how would it know what value should be passed in?

Comment: @casperOne: No. What is being exported here is a `System.Func<string,string>`. I've added an example of the importing class to clarify things.

Comment: I thought about it but it's against decoupling. I prefer to pass the config as part of the contract if it's not gonna be done automatically. This way exporter knows who is importing but it's against IoC yet.